# Client side pagination is not working using JSON in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid

I am new user for jQuery and jqGrid. I am trying to implement jqGrid with client side pagination. It is not working at my end. I am using .net 4.0 web service to get json response.

This is my web service code

```
 public string GetMessage(string FDate,string TDate,string Status)
{
 databaseDataContext dc = new databaseDataContext();
var v = (from v1 in dc.WBS_MESSAGEs
where v1.TransStatus ==  Status && v1.CreatedDate >= fromDate
                 && v1.CreatedDate <= toDate
                 select new
                 {
                     v1.MessageID,
                     v1.Task,
                     v1.Remark,
                     v1.CreatedDate,
                     Object = (v1.ObjectID == "2" ? "Business Partner" :
                         v1.ObjectID == "30" ? "Journals" : "Unknown")
                 });
        if (v.Count() > 0)
        {

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new 
                  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            return js.Serialize(v.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

This is my JavaScript / jqGrid code

```
function callMessage(p0, p1,p2,ctrlName) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SAPBOne.asmx/GetMessage",
                data: '{ "FDate":"' + p0 + '" ,"TDate":"' + p1 + '","Status":"' + p2 + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.statusText);
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    var thegrid = jQuery(ctrlName)[0];
                    thegrid.addJSONData(JSON.parse(data.d));
                    // var jSonMessage = JSON.parse(data.d); // data.d is a JSON formatted string, to turn it into a JSON object
                    // we use JSON.parse
                    // now that myData is a JSON object we can access its properties like normal
                }
            });
        };

  $(window).load(function () {
            var qString = get_query();
            //Get Success Messages
            jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid({
                url: callMessage(qString.p0, qString.p1,'Success','#jsonmap'), 
                datatype: 'json', 
                colNames: ['Message ID', 'Object', 'Task', "CreatedDate", 'Remark'],
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                colModel: [
                                { name: 'MessageID', index: 'MessageID asc', sortable: true, align: "center", width: 55 },
                                { name: 'Object', index: 'Object', width: 120, jsonmap: "Object" },
                                { name: 'Task', index: 'Task', width: 80, jsonmap: "Task", align: "center" },
                                { name: 'CreatedDate', index: 'CreatedDate', jsonmap: "CreatedDate", align: "center", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', newformat: 'd-M-y @ H:i:s' }, width: 140 },
                                { name: 'Remark', index: 'Remark', width: 300, jsonmap: "Remark" }
                            ],
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                }, 
                loadtext: "Loading...",
                rowNum:5,
                rowList: [5, 10],
                pager: '#pjmap', 
                sortname: 'MessageID', 
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                loadonce:true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                sortname: 'MessageID',
                caption: "Success",
                pgbuttons: true, 
                height: 'auto',
                refreshtext:'Refresh',
                repeatitems: true,
                emptyrecords: "No records to view"
            });
            jQuery("#jsonmap").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pjmap', { edit: false, add: false, del: false  });
```

I am stuck here.

Your help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: It seems your grid is not populated with data. is it?

Comment: Are you sure, only the pagination not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope there is no problem with your jQgrid definition. I have tried your code with local data. Its just works fine. Two things you need to check. First whether your ajax function returns the data from web service or not. Second, If it returns check whether it provides correct data type (in your case `json`).

I simplified your code by removing few lines from that,

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {

var mydata = [
  { MessageID: '1', Object: 'sample text', Task: 'Task 1', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '2', Object: 'sample 1', Task: 'Task 1', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '3', Object: 'sample 2', Task: 'Task 2', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '4', Object: 'sample 3', Task: 'Task 3', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '5', Object: 'sample 4', Task: 'Task 4', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '6', Object: 'sample 5', Task: 'Task 5', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '7', Object: 'sample 6', Task: 'Task 6', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '8', Object: 'sample 6', Task: 'Task 7', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '9', Object: 'sample 4', Task: 'Task 8', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '10',Object: 'sample 6', Task: 'Task 9', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '11',Object: 'sample 7', Task: 'Task 1', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'},
  { MessageID: '12',Object: 'sample 7', Task: 'Task 1', CreatedDate: '20140226',Remark: 'good'}
    ];

 jQuery("#listArray").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local', 
            data: mydata, 
            colNames: ['Message ID', 'Object', 'Task', "CreatedDate", 'Remark'],
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'MessageID', index: 'MessageID asc', sortable: true, align: "center", width: 55 },
                            { name: 'Object', index: 'Object', width: 120, jsonmap: "Object" },
                            { name: 'Task', index: 'Task', width: 80, jsonmap: "Task", align: "center" },
                            { name: 'CreatedDate', index: 'CreatedDate', jsonmap: "CreatedDate", align: "center", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'yyyyMMdd', newformat: 'd-M-y @ H:i:s' }, width: 140 },
                            { name: 'Remark', index: 'Remark', width: 300, jsonmap: "Remark" }
                        ],
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            rowNum:10,
            rowList: [10,20,50],
            pager: '#jqPager', 
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Success",
            height: 'auto',
            refreshtext:'Refresh',
            emptyrecords: "No records to view"
        });
        jQuery("#listArray").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false  });
```

Respective Html part,

```
<table id="listArray">
<tr>
    <td />
</tr>
</table>
<div id="jqPager"></div>
```

You can check the respective **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nawfT/37/)**.

Hope this helps you to identify your issue.

Comment: Hi Vinoth, Thanks for your reply... I tried your suggestion in the section, your code is working. I compare my code with your code, it does not have any difference except response.

Comment: All data come in one stroke... below is my json response... I see the difference in createdate response.

Comment: [{"MessageID":14,"Task":"U","Remark":"Customer updated in SAP Business One","CreatedDate":"\/Date(1393476527177)\/","Object":"Business Partner"}]... This is first record.. it has around 6 record and i set the paging to 2 rows

Comment: So you need to check the response data and modify your column definition according to that.

Comment: One more thing I have observed that this number(Created Date) is not indicating any sort of date. what kind of date format it is?. In your data you have mention correct date, but in grid it is showing some invalid date. (01-Jan-70 @ 00:00:00 good )

Comment: Please let me know what would be the response this jqGrid expected. I have give the response in the format which jqGrid is expected.

Comment: Hey... Thanks for your kind support. Issue resolve, Json was correct and parameters was also correct. The only thing I did is i set parameter 'localonly' after receiving json response and reload the the grid.

Comment: Can u please let me know how can mark your post as answer?